# how to make whole layout up of android keyboard

Tags: android

I have layout design and when I clicked on Edittext to write something the layout didn't up to show me the success button like the image. 
[image]

so I need to up my layout when keyboard display and I need to know how I can remove keyboard when I click on the layout or another widget.

my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".new_facture"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="60"
            android:textColor="@color/Gray" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Totale Prix:"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:textColor="@color/Gray">

            </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/total"
                android:text="0 MAD"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                >

            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/top" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="26dp"
                    android:text="Selecter le produit"></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/find_ic"
                        android:background="@color/float_transparent"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        ></ImageButton>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/rechercherdansLV"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
            ></EditText></RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout></LinearLayout>
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/productLV"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                ></ListView>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textquatity"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Quantité de produit"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/quatity"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/bord1"
                    android:hint="Quantité"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:digits="0123456789"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/addL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:text="ajouter des produits au facture"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"></Button>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                    android:text="NB"
                    android:textColor="@color/Gray" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"

                    android:text="Nom de produit"
                    android:textColor="@color/Gray" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"

                    android:text="Prix"
                    android:textColor="@color/Gray" />


            </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/productList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imprimer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:text="Imprimer"
            android:textColor="@color/white"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for U help.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in your manifest

```
<activity android:name="YourActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

after adding this line, when keyboard will open whole layout will move up and make space for keyboard and also when you press next on keyboard it will move to next editText if it is there.

Comment: When I use that attribute it didn't do anythink
`<activity android:name=".new_facture" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Addvente" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
        <activity android:name=".ui.gallery.AddCollection_vente" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>`